# AppFrameWork Animated Left Sidebar working great on emulator but neither Showing full nor Scrolling on Android Mobile Device

Tags: android, sidebar, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk, appframework

I have designed a page using Intel's XDK using Appframework with animated left sidebar its working properly on inbuilt emulator of XDK , on chrome but while I test the same code on android by creating  its apk (by building with xdk) sidebar neither showing full nor scrolls.
And when the page height is large sidebar scrolls with the page.

Steps that I follow on XDK:

Step1 : Added a footer , header and animated left sidebar by drag and drop.
Step2 : Added a button to toggle sidebar 
Step3 : Added enough list view to populate page
Step4 : build APK

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem.  I'll see what I can figure out about a workaround or getting it fixed.

Comment: I am also having same problem, and am stumped so far.